# I am trying to pull ldap server information from the ldap_servers table in drupal

Tags: database

I have a user search module in drupal that creates contact cards base on LDAP user information.  Everything works fine, I just need to make it more flexible, so that if the same module is used in a different drupal install, it can just set the same ldap server that is set in drupal.  Currently it is hard-coded.

first, I tried using this to get the server info:

```
  $ldapServer = db_query("SELECT address FROM ldap_servers WHERE `binddn` = 'cn=Directory Manager'");
  print_r( $ldapServer);
```

This is what the query returned:

> DatabaseStatementBase Object ( [dbh] => DatabaseConnection_mysql
>   Object ( [needsCleanup:protected] => [target:protected] => default
>   [key:protected] => default [logger:protected] =>
>   [transactionLayers:protected] => Array ( ) [driverClasses:protected]
>   => Array ( [MergeQuery] => MergeQuery [SelectQuery] => SelectQuery [UpdateQuery] => UpdateQuery [InsertQuery] => InsertQuery_mysql )
>   [statementClass:protected] => DatabaseStatementBase
>   [transactionSupport:protected] => 1
>   [transactionalDDLSupport:protected] => [temporaryNameIndex:protected]
>   => 0 [connectionOptions:protected] => Array ( [database] => tlsconnectapp [username] => drupal [password] => drupal [host] =>
>   localhost [port] => [driver] => mysql [prefix] => Array ( [default] =>
>   ) ) [schema:protected] => [prefixes:protected] => Array ( [default] =>
>   ) [prefixSearch:protected] => Array ( [0] => { [1] => } )
>   [prefixReplace:protected] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) ) [queryString]
>   => SELECT address FROM ldap_servers WHERE `binddn` = 'cn=Directory Manager' )

I'm sure I did something wrong, but I'm not sure what this means, and the server isn't in there.

Comment: I've also tried just using SELECT address FROM ldap_servers and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Please read on [Working with Result Sets](https://drupal.org/node/1251174) documentation. You have not issued the query yet to your database, you've only built a SELECT statement.

I also recommend installing the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module as you can get much more readable debug information from dpq() for queries or dpm() for Objects you want to inspect.